# spring java: interceptor sendRedirect loop

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i implemented a Interceptor that do certain checks and sendRedirect to some page. currently im testing it without any conditions, just simply sendRedirect when preHandle is called. this is my implementation:

```
class HttpInterceptorMgr implements HandlerInterceptor {
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServleRequest aRequest, HttpServletResponse aResponse, Object aHandler) {
     try {
      sendRedirect("/somepage");
      return false;
     }
     catch(Exceptio n e) {
      // Do something else
     }
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>myproject</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

....
<filter>
 <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
 <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
 <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
...
```

myproject-web-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />

<mvc:interceptors>
 <bean class="org.mycompany.HttpInterceptorMgr" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

applicationContextSecurityBeans.xml

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expression="true" access-denied-page="/user/denied">
 <security:form-login
   login-page="/login"
   authentication-failure-url="login?error=true"
   default-target-url="/homepage" />
 <security:logout invalidate-session="true"
   logout-success-url="/login"
   logout-url="/j_sring_security_logout" />
</security:http>
```

the problem i'm facing is that my page gets redirect in a loop. on firefox browser, it says "the page isn't redirectly properly". i tail catalina.out and it shows it enter prehandle multiple times and its request.getRequestUrl is `/somepage`. but im not able to reach the page successfully.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is because you have your Interceptor without a condition even for the redirect request to "/somepage" it is again sending a redirect and this will go through in a loop.

You can check whether the request is destined for "/somepage" if so you shouldn't redirect again.

```
class HttpInterceptorMgr implements HandlerInterceptor {
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServleRequest aRequest, HttpServletResponse aResponse, Object aHandler) {
     try {
      if(!aRequest.getRequestURL().toString().endswith("/somepage")) {
          sendRedirect("/somepage");
          return false;
      }          
     }
     catch(Exceptio n e) {
      // Do something else
     }
     return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi shazin, tks for the quick reply. ok i tried ur method, and now im getting a blank white page.